# can't get sessionStorage value

Tags: angular

am trying to get the sessionStorage value in user. But I can get only the bearer token value in the session storage.

```
   getSessionUser() {


    let currentUser = sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser');

    const heads = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': currentUser
    });

    return this.http.get<HttpResponse<Object>>(environment.apiURL + '/api/session', {headers: heads})
        .pipe(map(user => {
                sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                return user;
            },
            error => {
                //   console.log(error);
            }));
}
```

Comment: What's the matter? In code you provided you try to access and set different keys.

Comment: I have edited the code. can you check and give the solution?

Comment: as per the code, first time you might not get, after navigating to other pages come back and check.

Comment: write console.log(currentUser) after getItem. And check what is the value you are getting?

Comment: after navigation also couldn't get the session

Comment: current user value is null

Comment: Try to change sessionStorage to localStorage

Comment: same issue......

Comment: is user returned correctly from backend? what you get when console.log(user) in map mathod? btw. instead map, you can use tap

Comment: As far as I can see from the supplied code you are trying to get `currentUser` before you have even set it! You have to set `currentUser` before you can get it.

But your question is not completely clear to me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're requesting for currentUser before assignation of that value

```js
 getSessionUser() {

   const heads = new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': currentUser
    });

    this.http.get<HttpResponse<Object>>(environment.apiURL + '/api/session', {headers: heads})
        .pipe(map(user => {
                sessionStorage.setItem('currentUser', JSON.stringify(user));
                return user;
            },
            error => {
                //   console.log(error);
            }))
   let currentUser = sessionStorage.getItem('currentUser'); }
```

Comment: before complete of get request currentUser still won't be available